# How to build Boost 1.64 in 64 bits?

Tags: c++, boost

I am running Windows 10 and have Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition installed in my laptop.
I have some older programs that compiled fine in VS 2015 with Boost 1.62.0 in 64 bits.
For some very strange reason, I cannot find a way to compile say any library from Boost 1.64.0 (here filesystem and timer) using VS 2017 with this command line:

> b2  --build-dir=..\build_here  --with-filesystem   --with-timer --address-model=64

The command will execute and the libraries will be built, but in 32 bits!!

What could be going wrong?

Regards,
Juan Dent

Comment: For Visual Studio, you can skip this whole build step and just [get the binaries directly](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.64.0/)

Comment: If you get the binaries you need 14.1 x64 for Visual Studio 2017 64 bit.

Comment: Here is the command I used to build boost 1.60 for VS2013 x64 : ***X:/Other/Libraries/boost_1_60_0/bjam.exe -j%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% --without-python --without-mpi  address-model=64 --build-dir=X:/x64.13/VC.120/Libraries/Boost-1.60.0/build --prefix=X:/x64.13/VC.120/Libraries/Boost-1.60.0 --toolset=msvc-12.0 --build-type=complete stage install***

Comment: ***The command will execute and the libraries will be built, but in 32 bits!!*** Maybe you need to execute that from a Visual Studio 2017 x64 command prompt. I always build from the correct command prompt for 32 or 64 bit for the same version of the compiler I am targeting.

Comment: @drescherjm you are correct: the libraries are built but in 32 bits!!! Even when using the x64 command prompt... What now?

Comment: There was a specific problem with VS2017, they could not get bjam going.  It certainly is quite hard to do.  That was recent, somewhat doubtful they fixed it.  Yes, download the prebuilt binaries.

Comment: Did you clean the build folder between tries?

Comment: You can also use the Nuget Package for 14.1 instead.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, will try this first!

Comment: @ChristopherPisz where can I download the Nuget Package?

Comment: I expect that you download it directly in Visual Studio.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+use+Nuget+in+Visual+Studio&oq=How+to+use+Nuget+in+Visual+Studio&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6055j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @HansPassant do you know if they fixed it yet?

Answer (score 24):

To update the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257). `Visual Studio 2017` is a new toolset, so simply replace `toolset=msvc-14.0` (for `Visual Studio 2015`) with `toolset=msvc-14.1` i.e.:

In a Visual Studio tools Command Prompt:

```
cd boost_1_64_0
call bootstrap.bat
```

For static libraries (recommended for Windows):

```
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=complete stage
```

Note: thread must be built with dynamic linking see: https://studiofreya.com/2015/05/20/the-simplest-way-of-building-boost-1-58-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-architectures-with-visual-studio/

To build thread in a dynamic library:

```
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared --with-thread --build-type=minimal stage
```

> Note: the correct `b2` toolset for `Visual Studio 2017` is `msvc-14.1` **not** `msvc-15.0` and
>   the `b2` toolset for `Visual Studio 2019` is `msvc-14.2`.
>   If in doubt (and you've only one version of Visual Studio installed) just use `toolset=msvc`.

Comment: It was a helpful answer but where did you find documentation for the additional properties address-model and architecture?  It isn't shown in the output of b2 --help as a property or option.  I have yet to find it in the official boost build documentation either.

Comment: @shawn1874 they are defined here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/tools/build/doc/html/index.html#bbv2.overview.builtins.features in the boost b2 user manual,

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why, but the Boost is compiled with 32 bit same with the native x64 prompt of VS 2017.

This step-by-step worked for me:

1. Open x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017;
2. Changed the boost_1_66_0\project-config.jam to:

   `import option ; 
   //Check your compiler path here:
   using msvc : 14.1 : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"; 
   using mpi ;
   option.set keep-going : false ;`
3. Run:

   `b2.exe --toolset=msvc-14.1 --address-model=64 --architecture=x86 --runtime-link=static,shared --link=static threading=multi --build-dir=build\x64 install --prefix="C:\Program Files\Boost" -j4`

   or

   `bjam.exe toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 architecture=x86 runtime-link=static,shared link=static threading=multi  build-dir=build\x64 install prefix="C:\Program Files\Boost" -j4`

You should have a 64-bit = yes at the start of compilation.

Comment: this didn't seem to work for me, run #1 still yielded 32 bits at beginning of b2.exe and 2nd didn't even execute

Comment: I find that remove the "--" before address-model may help

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying
`architecture=ia64`

e.g.

```
b2.exe --toolset=msvc-14.1 --address-model=64 --architecture=ia64 --runtime-link=static,shared --link=static threading=multi --build-dir=build\x64 install --prefix="C:\Program Files\Boost" -j4
```

Comment: `x64` is not a valid value for `architecture`

Answer (score 1):

Consider saving a bunch of time by entering each boost version directory that you need and running there this:

```
bootstrap && b2 -a install
```

This way C:\Boost directory created with all possible combinations of library build options built including x64. You may want to turn this directory compression on.