# Building boost 1.65.0: vcvarsall.bat not found

Tags: boost, build, visual-studio-2017

I tried to build boost 1.65.0 using Visual Studio 2017 x64 and Windows 10.

[This](https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/percdems/src/8cbca6af8502d659c2afafe34cf19fe6c2f27a43/Build_boost_1_65_0_Visual%20Studio%2015%202017%20Win64.ps1?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) is how my power shell build script looks like:

```
. ".\Invoke-CmdScript.ps1"

# We expect PowerShell Version 5
if(-Not $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 5) {
    Write-Host "Expecting PowerShell Version 5"
    return
}

# Now download boost 1.65.0
Invoke-WebRequest http://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.65.0/source/boost_1_65_0.zip -OutFile C:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64\boost_1_65_0.zip

# Check file hash
$value = Get-FileHash C:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64\boost_1_65_0.zip -Algorithm SHA256

if($value.Hash -ne "f3f5c37be45eb6516c95cd147d8aa4abb9b52121fc3eccc1fc65c4af0cf48592") {
    Write-Host "boost archive seems to be corrupted"
    return
}

# Extract file
$strFileName="$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
If (Test-Path $strFileName){
    # Use 7-zip
    if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
    set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"  
    sz x C:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64\boost_1_65_0.zip -oC:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64
} Else {
    # use slow Windows stuff
    Expand-Archive C:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64\boost_1_65_0.zip -DestinationPath C:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64\boost_1_65_0
}

# Removed downloaded zip archive
Remove-Item C:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64\boost_1_65_0.zip

# Setup VS2017 x64 environment
Invoke-CmdScript -script "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" -parameters amd64

# Build
cd C:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64\boost_1_65_0
Invoke-CmdScript -script "bootstrap.bat"

$cpuInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Processor' `
    | Select-Object -Property 'DeviceID', 'Name', 'NumberOfCores', 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors';

Write-Host $cpuInfo.NumberOfLogicalProcessors

.\b2.exe --toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 --build-type=complete stage -j $cpuInfo.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

To boil it down – it simple does:

1. `bootstrap.bat`
2. `b2.exe --toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 --build-type=complete stage –j 8`

Execution bootstrap.bat seems to work. But b2 yields some errors – vcvarsall.bat not found:

[image]

Nevertheless, it seems that everything is build fine:

[image]

Is it safe to ignore those error messages?
Can someone reproduce those errors?

Comment: Note: the correct toolset for `b2` is `toolset=msvc-14.1` **not** `toolset=msvc-15.0`. I'm very sorry if you were mislaid by my old answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946538/how-to-build-boost-1-64-in-64-bits/43950508#43950508)

Comment: Ok, great that solves the issue - can you make an answer out of your comment so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you @Vertexwahn, I've posted a full answer for MSVC and MinGw, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update (and correct!) my previous answers on building boost, here are my latest notes for building `boost` on Windows for both `Visual Studio` and `MinGw`.

Windows does not directly support boost, so you can download it and put it  wherever you want.
The boost user guide recommends creating a `BOOST_ROOT`environment variable with the location of boost.

## Building for Visual Studio

In a Visual Studio tools Command Prompt:

```
cd boost_1_xx_0
call bootstrap.bat
```

For 64 bit static libraries (recommended for Windows):

```
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc address-model=64 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=complete stage
2>&1 | tee msvc_static_build.txt
```

Note: the `boost thread` library must be built with dynamic linking see: https://studiofreya.com/2015/05/20/the-simplest-way-of-building-boost-1-58-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-architectures-with-visual-studio/

For 64 bit dynamic library (thread only):

```
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc address-model=64 link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared --with-thread --build-type=minimal stage
2>&1 | tee msvc_thread_build.txt
```

If you have multiple versions of `Visual Studio` installed and want to build for a specific version then use:

- `Visual Studio 2017`: `toolset=msvc-14.1`
- `Visual Studio 2015`: `toolset=msvc-14.0`
- `Visual Studio 2013`: `toolset=msvc-12.0`
- `Visual Studio 2012`: `toolset=msvc-11.0`
- `Visual Studio 2010`: `toolset=msvc-10.0`

> Note: when I built `boost 1.65.0` for `Visual Studio 2017` for 64 bit binaries, `b2` output "building 32 bit: true", but it built 64 bit libraries...

Also note: whilst compiling a `boost 1.65.0` include file in `Visual Studio 2017` you may see the warning:

> Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

This is because the latest version of `Visual Studio 2017` defines `_MSC_VER` as 1911 whilst `boost\config\compilier\visualc.hpp` contains:

```
// last known and checked version is 19.10.25017 (VC++ 2017):
#if (_MSC_VER > 1910)
#  if defined(BOOST_ASSERT_CONFIG)
#     error "Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results"
#  else
#     pragma message("Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results")
#  endif
#endif
```

To remove the warning, change line 325 of `visualc.hpp` to:

```
#if (_MSC_VER > 1911)
```

## Building for MinGw

Ensure that `mingw` or `gcc` is in the path, e.g.: `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin`

```
cd boost_1_xx_0
call bootstrap.bat gcc

b2 toolset=gcc link=shared threading=multi --build-type=complete stage
2>&1 | tee mingw_build.txt
```

> Note: for boost versions *prior to* 1.61 change `bootstrap.bat gcc` to `bootstrap.bat mingw`

Also note: `2>&1 | tee name.txt` isn't necessary, but it's useful to keep a log...

Comment: "output "building 32 bit: true", but it built 64 bit libraries..." - are you sure it didn't make 32 bit libraries named as if they were 64 bit? That's not uncommon, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69317280/85371

Comment: Yes @sehe, I'm sure that they were 64 bit libraries because I built them into 64 bit `exe`s.