# Segmentation Fault running boost example

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-asio

I am trying to run the [autoecho program](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/fiber/examples/asio/autoecho.cpp) that uses boost::asio and boost::fiber. I am using the following:

- Ubuntu 16
- cmake 3.9.1
- boost 1_65_0

That program depends on a local copy of round_robin.hpp, yield.hpp and detail/yield.hpp. I have downloaded all of those and the program builds successfully. When I run the code, I get a segmentation fault at the line in main that does:

```
io_svc->run();
```

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong, or if the code has an error in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an email from Oliver Kowalke @boost:

unfortunately, some fixes did not permission to merged into 1.65 (no permission because too late) - you could use branch develop (github) or you need to wait till 1.66is released.

So, until boost 1.66 is released, this code will not work unless you want to use the develop branch.

Comment: on a less important note `boost 1.65.0` also reports false compilation warnings with the latest relaease of `Visual Studio 2017`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838714/building-boost-1-65-0-vcvarsall-bat-not-found/45842161#45842161