# Problems with building Boost 64bit on Windows: It's still build 32bit

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, 64-bit

I have quite strange problem with building Boost library on Windows for Windows in 64bit format.

I'm using the guide from Getting Started boost documentation. My boost building command looks like this:

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 --build-dir="c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build\x64Win" --stagedir="c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\stage" -sBZIP2_SOURCE=c:\agent\_work\46\s\bzip2 -sZLIB_SOURCE=c:\agent\_work\46\s\zlib --build-type=minimal stage -j6
```

But, the b2 tool somehow ignores my address-model setting and its building 32bit version which is stated in configuration checks:

```
...found 15 targets...
...updating 8 targets...
common.mkdir c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build
common.mkdir c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build\x64Win
common.mkdir c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build\x64Win\boost
common.mkdir c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build\x64Win\boost\architecture
common.mkdir c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build\x64Win\boost\architecture\msvc-14.0
common.mkdir c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build\x64Win\boost\architecture\msvc-14.0\debug
common.mkdir c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build\x64Win\boost\architecture\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi
compile-c-c++ c:\agent\_work\46\s\Boost\Build\x64Win\boost\architecture\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\32.obj
32.cpp
...updated 8 targets...
Performing configuration checks
    - 32-bit                   : yes
```

Im trying to build it on Windows 7 64bit and on VM with Windows Server 2012 64bit. Maybe someone had similar problems and got a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your build command looks similar to my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838714/building-boost-1-65-0-vcvarsall-bat-not-found/45842161#45842161)... Are you running it from an MSVC 64bit Command prompt?

Comment: Quote: "Note: when I built boost 1.65.0 for Visual Studio 2017 for 64 bit binaries, b2 output "building 32 bit: true", but it built 64 bit libraries..."  Oh dear.  Do consider passing that nasty job [to somebody else](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/).

Comment: I tried to build boost 1.66.0 in Windows 10 64 bit using VS 2017 x64 shell, but its building 32 bit and give me a lot of error when I try to use the generated libs.