# Installation Boost Library on Visual Studio2017

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS2017 and Windows10.

I'm trying to install Boost library but I cannot find any b2, bjam file in my

folder after I executed bootstrap.bat.

There is no any sign of error and I downloaded Version 1.65.1.

Comment: Did you run `bootstrap` in a Visual Studio tools Command Prompt? Try following the instructions I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838714/building-boost-1-65-0-vcvarsall-bat-not-found/45842161#45842161)

Comment: OH It works!! I should run that in a VS Command Prompt! Thanks!