# Building boost filesystem static 64 bit not finishing

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, build

I want to build the boost filesystem lib as a static library in 64 bit. I use:

- Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.2.0
- Windows 10 Professional
- Boost Version 1.70.0

First I used call `bootstrap.bat` from thr boost root directory. Then I tried the build command from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43950508/7277003) answer:

```
.\b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.2 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=complete stage
```

I also tried the following command:

```
.\b2 -j8 toolset=msvc address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --with-filesystem stage
```

**Problem**: Nothing really happens. I have waited already for several hours and, according to the task manager, `b2.exe` is still running but I don't get *any* output printed into the console window. I would expect at least some kind of progress messages?

Also, with the second command, shouldn't the build be rather fast as it should only compile the filesystem library?

I tried running the command from the powershell and the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2019", but that didn't change anything.

**Question**: Am I doing something wrong? Unfortunatly, quite a lot links in the boost documentation seem to be broken...

Comment: Do you really need to compile it from source? I also tried to go down that road without much success. I ended up using the precompiled binaries available using [Miniconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/boost).

Comment: @apalomer But shouldn't it be pretty easy according to the doc? I would really prefer to be able to build it, I remember it worked flawless some years ago with an old version of boost...

Comment: Would using [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) be an option? Using it, I have been able to install any boost(or other) library very cleanly.

Comment: @Tau with installing, do you mean buidling actual boost binaries? Or is that only some kind of download manager for already built libraries?